# Django can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

Tags: django

Django can only concatenate str (not "list") to str
Error Messages.......

I have some code like this:

```
function form_submit() {
    var arr_category = new Array();
    var arr_lawyer = new Array();
    var data = new Object();

    $('input[name^="category_idx"]').each(function() {
        arr_category.push($(this).val());
    });

    $('input[name^="lawyer_idx"]').each(function() {
        arr_lawyer.push($(this).val());
    });

    console.log("arr_category=="+arr_category);
    console.log("arr_lawyer=="+arr_lawyer);

    if (confirm('edit??') == true) {
        data.arr_category = arr_category;
        data.arr_lawyer = arr_lawyer;
        call_ajax('/admin/lawyer/recommend_add', data);
        //alert("arr_lawyer=="+arr_lawyer);
    }
}
```

Am I doing well in jquery?
look at console.log

```
arr_category==1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
arr_lawyer==64,37,57,58,130,62,38,51,110
```

admin_view.py

```
@csrf_exempt
def recommend_add(request):

    print("TEST BANG VALUE------------")
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":

        arr_category = request.GET.getlist('arr_category[]')
        print("arr_category------------" + arr_category)

    code = 0
    msg = "TEST."

    data = json.dumps({
        'code': code,
        'msg': msg,
        #'retURL': retURL

    })
    return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

I want to print.
error message
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case if you want to return a python interpreter error message to jquery's ajax call then you can use the below syntax.

```
def recommend_add(request):
 print("TEST BANG VALUE------------")
 if request.is_ajax() and request.method == "POST":
   try:
     arr_category = request.GET.getlist('arr_category[]')
     print("arr_category------------" + arr_category)
     code = 0
     msg = "Success"
   except Exception as e:
     code = '' # anything you want as per your internal logic in case of error.
     msg = str(e)

 data = json.dumps({
    'code': code,
    'msg': msg,
    #'retURL': retURL

 })
 return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

Please ignore my indentation.

Answer (score 0):

in your print code try this

```
print("arr_category------------:", arr_category)
```

Comment: Print---> arr_category------------: []

Comment: in your function you post a data object so to check in your function if data is posted try this   data = request.POST['data']  and then print data. arr_category is empty because you dont post the arr_category. Also inside the post block you have request.GET